# Add GitLab private repository as Maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, gitlab, egit

I have a private repository in GitLab (it's in a group, and I have a Developer role) which I want to add as a dependency for my Maven project.

I've been looking for a while and all I found was that I have to add the following to my pom.xml:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>gitlab-maven</id>
    <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/.../packages/maven</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>

<distributionManagement>
  <repository>
    <id>gitlab-maven</id>
    <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/.../packages/maven</url>
  </repository>
  <snapshotRepository>
    <id>gitlab-maven</id>
    <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/.../packages/maven</url>
  </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

However, I have no idea how to add the dependency itself (with the groupId and stuff) and I'm not sure how to do authentication to allow Maven to download the project. I've seen something about Personal Access Tokens in GitLab, but I'm not sure how to set that up (I assume I'd only need read-only access?).

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/using-github-as-maven-repository could be helpful to read how you need to implement the repository

Answer (score 19):

First, a few pre-requisites. Since you mentioned you're using a private repository, you'll need to have at least GitLab Silver (hosted on gitlab.com) or GitLab Premium (self-hosted) in order to use the [GitLab Maven Packages repository](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/packages/maven.html). Also, if you're self-hosted, you'll need to be on [GitLab 11.3](https://about.gitlab.com/2018/09/22/gitlab-11-3-released/) or later (should be out this time next week), and have `packages_enabled` set to true (see [Enabling the Packages repository](https://bag.org.tr/proje/help/administration/packages.md#enabling-the-packages-feature)).

For private projects, you'll need a [Personal Access Token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html). The token should have the `api` scope for Maven to upload artifacts to GitLab. Once you have the token, you configure your `settings.xml` like this.

```
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>gitlab-maven</id>
      <configuration>
        <httpHeaders>
          <property>
            <name>Private-Token</name>
            <value>REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN</value>
          </property>
        </httpHeaders>
      </configuration>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

In `pom.xml`, where you have the ellipses, you need to fill in your project ID. To find the ID, just visit the front page of your project on GitLab. It's shown near the top of the pages, just after the name and description of your project. For example, take a look at the [mvn-example](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/examples/mvn-example) sample project. Its project ID is 8377576. That goes in the URL.

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>gitlab-maven</id>
    <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/8377576/packages/maven</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

The [mvn-example project's pom.xml file](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/examples/mvn-example/blob/master/pom.xml) shows a completed example.

With all that set up, you should be able to upload artifacts with `mvn deploy`.

Comment: Gitlab has moved the private maven repository feature to Core from EE.   https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/221259#proposal

Comment: Is it possible to encrypt the property value for the personal access token like it is possible for password or passphase?

Answer (score 8):

First of all you should go to your projects "Packages and Registries" it is on the left menu of your Gitlab user interface and find there package registry button(if you can't see it just ask your system administrator) and just leave that tab open and wait for future instructions.
Be aware that if you work in a company that has Gitlab domain, everywhere that I write "https://gitlab.com",  you should write your company's gitlab domain.
After that you should generate your "Private-Token" by going to "https://gitlab.com/profile" -> "access tokens" and select api check box and give a name to your token for example "test token" and then press generate.
After that in your java project create file "settings.xml" near your pom.xml and paste there following piece of code that is below and write there your token that you just generated. This settings.xml is required both for uploading and installing artifact.

```
 <settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>gitlab-maven</id>
      <configuration>
        <httpHeaders>
          <property>
            <name>Private-Token</name>
            <value>your token</value>
          </property>
        </httpHeaders>
      </configuration>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

After that go to Gitlab's user inreface and copy your project's id from there. See screenshot:[image: project id]
After that paste following code that is below in your pom.xml. This must be done in the project that should be uploaded in Gitlab's "package registry"

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/project_id/packages/maven</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/project_id/packages/maven</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

For uploading artifact open terminal in your ide and paste following command:

```
mvn deploy -s settings.xml
```

After that go to "package registry" of your project in Gitlab user interface and see there uploaded artifact.

For installing the settings.xml also needed, and also paste following piece of code that is below in your pom.xml

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/project_id/packages/maven</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

And in your terminal call: `mvn install -s settings.xml` or `mvn dependency:get -Dartifact={groupId}:{artifactId}:{version}`
If there is an error while installing, don't worry, got to your local computer's .m2 folder, find that folder with containing new created artifact(jar), delete it and then go and call the same terminal command once again.

Answer (score 0):

To use your private repository as maven dependency go to your package Registry and click on the package(com/example/demo)

you will see the instruction to add the dependency.

You need to add  tag with correct dependency and  and  tag.

if you will mention private repository url in both  and , it will pull and push the artefact from the private repository.

If you want to use the private repository to only download the dependency and push your artifact to the current project registry, then you need to add the  and  tag of the private repository and  tag will the current project one.

Scenario 1:-

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/36104875/packages/maven</url>
      </repository>
    </repositories>
    
    <distributionManagement>
      <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/36104875/packages/maven</url>
      </repository>
    
      <snapshotRepository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/36104875/packages/maven</url>
      </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

2nd scenario:-

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>gitlab-maven</id>
    <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/36104875/packages/maven</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>

<distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/maven</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
```